# Print web URL's output on SQL Server column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a Microsoft SQL server table with just one column i.e. USERID.

```
USERID
ID_001
ID_002
ID_003
...
```

I need to print another column which should be output of a URL. Here URL would be something like:

http://chatStatus.abc.com/cgi-bin/getStatus.pl?id=ID_001
This webpage, when opened in browser, shows me a plain text string containing user's chat messenger status, like following: 
Online|Available|http://abc999.vci.pqr.com/webmedia/webpresence/BulbLit.gif|Free for 1 hour and 43 minutes|Free for 1 hour and 43 minutes|My_Messenger_Status_xyz

I need a SQL Query so that I can print two columns (where STATUS is everything after 5th "|" sign:

```
USERID | STATUS
ID_001 | My_Messenger_Status_xyz
ID_002 | My_Messenger_Status_pqr
```

Request you to please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: SQL Server is a database system, not a web browser. Your client is in a much better position to issue HTTP requests. Fetch your DB data, loop over it to get data from the remote web server, combine results.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert